# Android Device Not Found (Recognised) On Ubuntu Natty

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, natty

I have done some Android development on Windows using Eclipse and everything worked just fine... Now I installed Eclipse on Ubuntu and downloaded the SDK and stuff, made a udev rule (in 99-android.rule file, because I am using 11.04), restarted everything several times and nothing seems to work. *adb devices* gives me this result:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    device
```

I see the same using Eclipse, it says it's *online* but when I choose it I get an error message saying ADB rejected installation because *device not found*

Any tips or something?

Comment: What device are you using ? Had similar issues with a Nexus S. Brought me back to Windows...

Comment: Try changing the USB connection settings from within the phone.

Answer (score 2):

What I would start trying is make sure the device is in USB debugging mode. After that try adb kill-server and then adb start-server from the command line. After that make sure the rules file is there and has the correct vendor id in it. The rules file you made needs to be placed in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules and mine looks like this

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="[YOUR VENDOR ID]", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev" 
TEST=="/var/run/ConsoleKit/database", \ 
RUN+="udev-acl --action=$env{action} --device=$env{DEVNAME}"`

You need to replace the correct vendor id in the first line above. To get that you run "lsusb" from the command line and it will give you a list. Just find the one that looks like it describes your device and take the ####:#### part of the line and replace the "[YOUR VENDOR ID]" part from above.

Now make that file executable using "chmod +x /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules" and restart udev "service udev restart"

This should fix your problem. Also maybe kill and start ADB again to be sure. This is what worked for me a while back. If this doesn't do it then I am not sure exactly. I have heard of other things being added to these rules files depending on your specific device.

Comment: If that doesn't work maybe try to create a .ini file under "~/.android/adb.ini" and put this in that file...

1\n
0x[YOUR VENDOR ID]

replace the [YOUR VENDOR ID] with the first part of the vendor id found in the lsusb command. or go to this web address and get the vendor id for your device http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html Also the \n from above just means that the 1 is supposed to be on the first line haha

Now restart just to be safe and plug the device in. Just another thing to try I suppose.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me :) My previous rules file looked very similar but maybe I had some mistake in it or something... I simply copy-pasted this one, taped my vendor id and restarted my computer. Now I have another problem - no permissions but it's a different one - the one I asked help for is fixed :P

Comment: OK, so I fixed the no permissions problem using sudo adb start-server. Now I have a problem. adb devices shows ????????? device but it still says device not found (although it shows in the list and I select to run on it) in Eclipse.